# echo the value of another echo statement

Tags: bash, environment-variables, sh, environment

I have environment variables TEST_GC_NAME, mini, fries and salmon2.

Their values are as follows:

```
export TEST_GC_NAME=hamburger
export mini=TEST
export fries=_GC_NAME 
export salmon2="\$$mini$fries"
```

When I echo `salmon2`, I get `$TEST_GC_NAME`.

Example:

```
echo $salmon2
```

result: `$TEST_GC_NAME`

How can I echo `$salmon2` in such a way that I get `hamburger`.

Comment: This question has the "sh" tag. Do you really need a portable solution for this, or is the target shell only Bash?

Comment: if I set salmon2="echo \$$mini$fries", make another variable called salmon3=$(eval $salmon2), and finally echo $salmon3, that solves the issue